# Magento 2 - How to create item wise shipment And add tracking number programmatically

Tags: magento2, shipment, shipment-tracking

We need to create programmatically shipment and add tracking number for all the ordered items from CSV.

Check following CSV sample data for your reference.

> order_no,sku,quantity,tracking_no
>
> 700100,JK5012,1,132131315
>
> 700100,KM5013,2,132131316

Can anyone help us with the above requirement?

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To do this,
you can use trackfactory of magento 2 and within it's execute function you can get data from your csv file for example order number and sku and underneath it within foreach loop, you can add these lines

```
$track = $this->_trackFactory->create();
    $track->setCarrierCode($carrierCode);
    $track->setDescription($description);
    $track->setTrackNumber($trackingNumber);
    $shipment->addTrack($track);
    $this->_shipmentRepository->save($shipment);
$this->_shipmentNotifier->notify($shipment);
```

this is how your file looks like

```
/** @var Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentRepository */
protected $_shipmentRepository;

/** @var Magento\Shipping\Model\ShipmentNotifier */
protected $_shipmentNotifier;

/** @var Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\TrackFactory */
protected $_trackFactory

public function __construct(
  \Magento\Shipping\Model\ShipmentNotifier $shipmentNotifier, 
  \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentRepository $shipmentRepository, 
  \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\TrackFactory $trackFactory)
{
  $this->_shipmentNotifier = $shipmentNotifier;
  $this->_shipmentRepository = $shipmentRepository;
  $this->_trackFactory = $trackFactory;
}
public execute(){
//your code here for getting data from csv and pass it to foreach loop to add tracking number to order from csv file
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Is your solution working with cron?

Comment: yes, you can implement it with cron as well

Comment: @John can you help out on this similar question? It will be one tracking per order. (My csv is order# | carrier | tracking) Thanks in advance. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268844/adding-tracking-number-to-existing-orders-from-csv-file-programmatically-in-mage

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. do you have the final code for your question? I might be able to use as a reference, thank you.